# is httpContext.Request.GetRawBodyStringAsync() the same as [FromBody] string body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to get my head around things (sorry for stupid questions).
I get a message request from an Apple device client to my wep api and I am wondering how to handle it. In .NET Framework, I used to handle the message using:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Server(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var message =  await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This worked fine but moving to .NET Core, request is always empty. Hence I've moved on to doing this (this works below):

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("server")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
{
    var requestBody = await HttpContext.Request.GetRawBodyStringAsync();
}
```

But I am wondering if the above is the correct way of handling such requests and I have also see the use of [FromBody] and wondering it's better to use that but it does not work for me.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("server")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] string requestBody)
{
   //doesn't get called?
}
```

Comment: [FromBody] is used to indicate that the value should be inferred from body of the request. There are several other places where the value can be inferred from, which you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: What is GetRawBodyStringAsync?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter name in your action needs to match the property name being sent in the request.

e.g. if the request is sending:
`varA=string1&varB=string2&varc=string3`

Then your action method should look like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("server")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] string varA,[FromBody] string varB,[FromBody] string varC)
{

}
```

Alternatively, you can have a model class for these type of requests:

```
class RequestModel{
public string VarA {get;set;}
public string VarB {get;set;}
public string VarC {get;set;}
}

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("server")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] RequestModel request)
    {

    }
```

Comment: **Note:** you can't use multiple [FromBody] parameters in the same request. The above was just for explanation purposes. You should use the complex type approach if passing multiple values from the request body.